# Penalty for overstaying tourist visa in Taiwan

Tags: visas, legal, customs-and-immigration, taiwan, overstaying

In Taiwan, what is the penalty for overstaying a tourist visa with legitimate reasons (for example, a flight was cancelled or delayed, or a transportation closure made someone miss getting to the airport in time)? What fines or barriers to future travel would someone face?

Comment: I don't think transportation closure or lateness is considered as a 'legitimate' reason anywhere in the world when considered overstaying.

Comment: Also, I've noticed a few questions about Taiwan from you. A lot of this can be answered search http://www.forumosa.com. It is the expat forums in Taiwan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Penalties are levied via a fine.  The fine ranges from around 1000 NTD (if you overstay by an hour) up to 10000 NTD.

Source (page 5) http://iff.immigration.gov.tw/public/Data/11714474471.pdf

Comment: Do note that although the page linked here currently states the minimum is $1000 NTD for an overstay of 10 days or less, that [another answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67527/140) contributed a personal experience that an overstay of less than 1 day cost him double that. So in this case the official government source does not seem trustworthy.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by Michael Pryor, there is a fine. Any natural force is still your responsibility, including typhoons. From my understanding, the only way you can overstay your visa is by government mandate (quarantine, jail, etc).

That being said, I have overstayed a visa by 2 days and didn't have to pay anything because there was a typhoon. Really, it is up to the discretion of the immigration officer you meet. Also note, that you can be jailed for up to 2 MONTHS if you overstay. I have never heard of that being used except in the case of a suspected drug smuggler though . Your best bet is to check the weather forecast. If you absolutely can't get out on the last day of your visa, just accept the fact that you will have to pay some cash.

Answer (score 2):

I was charged "Over Stay" even though my visa waiver had run out less than 24 Hours. All because I had missed my flight by a few hours!

That was because I checked in on the same day as flight but I should have checked in the night before as my flight was just past midnight.
(Slight oversight on my part, not checking the time and date correctly,
so my flight had already gone some 22 hours earlier)

So their Immigration told me I was 90+1 Days and I had to pay a penalty charge. 
Even though it was less than 24 Hours, they hit me a with a hard 2,000 NTD$ (£40) charge.

I guess I was a bit miffed as I was only expecting a small fine, no more than 1000 NTD$ anyway.

I kindly tried to argue that I had already paid 11,200 NTD$ for the change in the flight ticket so I could leave on the next flight in less than a couple of hours.

This fell on deaf ears and after a few minutes I was surrounded by 5 or 6 armed airport security.

I was told that if I refused to pay the fine, I would be arrested and taken to a detention office, where I could be transferred to a jail and would end up paying a lot more before I would be released to be allowed to go home.

Understandably, I backed down and paid the fine so their immigration would give me the necessary paperwork for me to proceed out of there.

If anything, it's taught me a valuable, if not expensive lesson.

Do not miss your flight or stay past the time you are allowed to stay.
To say their airport immigration is very strict is an understatement.

Comment: This answer is very much a rant. While I understand your anger, the fact remains that you did overstay.

Comment: You overstayed. It was entirely your own fault. They fined you a tiny amount (I'm sorry, but £40 is almost nothing to anybody who can afford to travel internationally). So, really, I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: This is more of a rant than Carl's. Millions of poor people travel internationally every day. I assume you are giving tiny £40 amounts to beggars and charities every day as someone who can afford to travel internationally. God bless you for that at least. Voted up since this informative answer tells us that in reality you are likely to have to pay double the amount stated in the official document [linked to by Michael Pryor](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/939/140).

Comment: @hippietrail Paying nearly £15,000 a year is an utterly ridiculous comparison to a completely avoidable one-off expense of £40.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Then offer to pay it for him or stop telling people that in your opinion they either have no right to travel or no right to be grumpy. Carl earned his very minor gripe and posted valuable information. You are grumpily telling people how to live by your personal standards without earning any similar right to do so and have added nothing to the question or answer.

Comment: @hippietrail: he actually got lucky. In several countries - like Russia - if you overstay your visa, it would be such hassle to leave the country that you'd be extremely happy if they just let you pay $500 and leave. For my friend, who overstayed a Russian visa for **one hour** because of plane delay (so he couldn't check in timely and thus clear passport control) it took an extra week in Russia to obtain visa extension, and way more in expenses; some expats said he was lucky to have it done so fast. One should be glad Taiwan didn't let him through the same miserable experience.